# Is it possible to have two same Windows 8 apps installed side by side?

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime, microsoft-metro

Is there a way how to **install side by side the Store version of my app and the development version of my app from Visual Studio**? I've already published several apps I want to publish an update.
If I try it from VS2012, I got a message that app with that Id is already installed and I have to uninstall the Store app before deploying the new one from Visual Studio. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is definitely possible, you just need to make sure your dev version uses a separate Package ID. You can set this up by opening the Package.appxmanifest, selecting the "Packaging" tab and use "Choose certificate". Choose "Create test certificate" in the dropdown to create a separate testcertificate.

When creating app packages for the store the package will be associated with the store certificate again.

Comment: Thanks, it works - I've generated new test certificate and then I had to change the "Package name" as well.